# SonataAdminBundle without intl extension

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, sonata-admin

I'm having problems with SonataAdminBundle when editing or creating:

> The Symfony\Component\Locale\Stub\StubNumberFormatter::getSymbol() is
>   not implemented. Please install the 'intl' extension for full
>   localization capabilities.

or

> Fatal error: Class 'ResourceBundle' not found in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony2\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Locale\Locale.php
>   on line 157

I cant install php extensions in my basic hosting

I found [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6045#issuecomment-16046955), but it just works when `NumberFormatter` is called, obviously I have to create each class needed to call the intl extension but I asks here to expert to see any others ways solution/workaround/suggestion to get work without the intl extension

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function getSymbole not defined in Symfony\Component\Locale\Stub\StubNumberFormatter. This method throws an exception, this is its body :

```
  public function getSymbol($attr)
{
    throw new MethodNotImplementedException(__METHOD__);
}
```

It should be implemented to remove this exception, you can modefied like this :

```
        public function getSymbol($attr)
    {
    switch($attr) {
      case self::CURRENCY_SYMBOL:
        return '$';
      case self::DECIMAL_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL:
        return '.';
      case self::DIGIT_SYMBOL:
        return '#';
      case self::EXPONENTIAL_SYMBOL:
        return 'E';
      case self::GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL:
        return ',';
        ;
  }
```

This modification works fine with me, I had the same problem. But if you upgrade your symfony version via composer you may lose your modification.